# What's limiting the depth of a recursive symlink chain?

Tags: filesystems, symlink

Out of curiosity, I ran the following:

```
mkdir haha
cd haha
ln -s ../haha haha
```

Which created a recursive structure like this:

```
  ┌────────┐
  V        │
haha/      │
  haha/────┘
```

I wanted to see how deep into this I could go, so I typed `cd haha/` and held down <kbd>Tab</kbd> to have bash autocomplete a whole bunch of `haha/`s. It autocompleted up to `cd haha/haha/<SNIP>/haha/` (a total of 40 "haha/"s) before it suddenly stopped completing any more (weird behavior #1). I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Running `pwd`, I saw I was indeed in the directory `/home/me/haha/<SNIP>/haha/haha` (41 "haha/"s). From within this directory, I ran another `cd haha`, which suddenly teleported me all the way back to `/home/me/haha` (as confirmed by another `pwd`). Huh? Why does this happen, is it a bash quirk? Filesystem limit (I'm using btrfs)? Something else?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "recursive" symlink chain.  You are referring to a "circular" symlink chain. Recursion eventually resolves, but infinite loops never do.

Comment: Kernel has own limits, and usually programs follows (or better:L they uses kernel). But bash as you see, handle PWD and so links in `cd` differently (or better the `..`). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456784/behavior-of-cd-bash-on-symbolic-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `cd haha/haha/...`, or really use any path symlinks, the kernel has to resolve the links to figure out where the path points to. In Linux, there's a limit to how many links it resolves before bailing out with "Too many levels of symbolic links" (ELOOP).

The [path_resolution(7) man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) mentions that 40 link limit:

> In order to protect the kernel against stack overflow, and
> also to protect against denial of service, there are limits on
> the maximum recursion depth, and on the maximum number of
> symbolic links followed.  An ELOOP error is returned when the
> maximum is exceeded ("Too many levels of symbolic links").
>
> [...] In Linux
> 4.2, the kernel's pathname-resolution code was reworked to
> eliminate the use of recursion, so that the only limit that
> remains is the maximum of 40 resolutions for the entire pathname.

When you repeat the tab completion, what happens it that the shell asks for a directory listing of `haha/`, then `haha/haha/`, etc. until at some point the OS refuses to play and drops the error. It looks like the tab-completion routine doesn't expose that error to the user, probably in order not to be too noisy. If you tried `cd haha/...` with a too long path, you'd get the error. But with a path that's just under the limit, it works.

By default, the shell tries to remember the path you used to get to a directory, so that `pwd` shows the path with links, and doing `cd foo; cd ..` gets you back to where you started with, regardless of if `foo` was a link.

When at the limit, doing `cd haha` leads to Bash first calling `chdir(".../haha/haha")` with the *whole* path, which now has too many links, and the call fails. After that, the shell stops trying to be fancy and just calls `chdir("haha")` instead and resolves the current location with `getcwd()`, getting a path without any links in it.